# Empty path name is not legal

Tags: c#, xml, string, stringbuilder, xmlwriter

I got this error:

> Empty path name is not legal.

What is the problem with my code?

```
StringBuilder writer = new StringBuilder();
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings() { OmitXmlDeclaration = true };
XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(strXML, settings);
xmlDoc.Save(xmlWriter);
strXML = writer.ToString();
```

Comment: What's `strXML` in `XmlWriter.Create(strXML, settings)`?

Comment: You have an empty path... it's not legal...

Comment: please send the value of strXML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear what you're trying to accomplish - the code sample provided doesn't actually compile.

However, this does and seems to have no issues:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings() { OmitXmlDeclaration = true };
XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("xml.txt", settings);
xmlDoc.Save(xmlWriter);
```